# How to get createContainer & Collection working outside of main jsx

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm a novice to Meteor/React.js applications, and while I've been able to cobble together an app with multiple components by passing the App.jsx collections around as props, I can't seem to get individual components to handle their own collections.  My rational is that some components need the collection fetched in one order, while others need the collection fetched in another.  It seems silly to pass around a collection and then have to manipulate it internally to get the proper effect when a new sort is what's needed.  My main App.jsx has:

```
App.propTypes = {
  workdone:PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  subjects:PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
    workdone: WorkDoneCollection.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1}}).fetch(),
    subjects: SubjectCollection.find({},{sort:{subject:1}}).fetch()
  };
}, App);
```

and if I pass the props.workdone on to another component everything works fine.  On the other hand if I try a set up an independent collection in the other component, like this:

```
WorkSummary.propTypes = {
  workdone:PropTypes.array
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
    workdone: WorkDoneCollection.find({},{sort:{createdAt:1}}).fetch()
  };
}, WorkSummary);
```

the workdone property is undefined.

Comment: How do you import `WorkSummary` in `App.jsx`?

Comment: import WorkSummary from './WorkSummary.jsx' then using it is just: <WorkSummary workdone={this.props.workdone}></WorkSummary>